# Dynamic replacement of values with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some data in the form

```
[
    {
        "name": "alex",
        "fullname": "Alessandro Magno"
    },
    {
        "name": "alex",
        "fullname": "Alessandro Magno"
    }
]
```

but (name and fullname) are not fixed, they may be "key"/"value", or whatever.
I'm also given a template to follow, e.g.:

```
var template = "<span>data.fullname (data.name)</span>".
```

My problem is the following:

- I have to look for all the "data." in the string,
- obtain the value following it (in this case, fullname and name),
- and replace data. with my external source. E.g.

  ```
  str.replace("data.<value>", source[value]);
  ```

In Javascript.

Thanks!

EDIT: I probably explained it wrongly. My source is defined (in this case, a name/fullname list in JSON format). I also have a template to follow. I have to replace the syntax used in the template (which is "data." ['data.' is fixed]) with the correspondent value of the source. Hope this is clearer now!

Re-thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `replace` call using a string will only replace a single instance of a substring. You'll have to use a regular expression.
Looking at what you're trying to do, I'd say you're probably looking for something like:

```
var s = "<span>data.fullname (data.name)</span>";
var replacements = {name: 'alex', fullname: 'alessandro'};//example
s.replace(/(data\.)([a-z]+)/g, function(a,b,c)
{
    return b + (repl[c] || 'none');
});
```

This results in *"data.alessandro (data.alex)"*
How it works? Central to this approach is the regular expression:

`/(data\.)([a-z]+)/g`, which is quite basic:

- `(data\.)`: match *and capture* the literal string *"data."*
- `([a-z]+)`: again: match & capture 1 or more chars fater data. -> *"data."*
- `g`: is the global flag, apply this patter to the entire string.

Now, for each match for this pattern that is found, instead of providing a replacement string, I provide a function, that is passed the matched substring (and the captured groups as separate arguments), and use the function construct a replacement string:

```
function(a, b, c)
{//a -> entire substring, b-> data., c-> string after data.
    return b + (replacements[c] || 'none');// logical || to provide default string replacement
}
```

It's as simple as that, really. Given that your values are contained by objects, that are in an array, you could opt to code the following:

```
var vals = [{name: 'alex', fullname: 'alessandro'},{name: 'alex2', fullname: 'alessandro2'}],
results =[],
template = "<span>data.fullname (data.name)</span>";
for (var i=0;i<vals.length;++i)
    results[i] = template.replace(/(data\.)([a-z]+)/g, function(a,b,c)
    {
        return b + (vals[i][c] || 'default');
    });
```

*Edit:*
To remove `data.` substring, too, change the callback function (and pattern) to:

```
s.replace(/data\.([a-z]+)/function(a,c)
{
    return replacements[c] || 'none';
});
```

In case of the code above:

```
for (var i=0;i<vals.length;++i)
    results[i] = template.replace(/data\.([a-z]+)/g, function(a,c)
    {
        return vals[i][c] || 'default';
    });
```

Is what you're after

Comment: Exactly! If I could delete "data." as well it would be perfect! (Yes, regular expressions are still on my to do list!)

Comment: @alex89x: Edited my answer to better fit what you need to do

Comment: Just change "returb" to return and it's perfect! Thank you very much (for the explanation, too!)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a template you could use `template engine`. Basically it will allow you to bind an object to a template. Behind the scene the template is parsed using regex. Pseudo-code:

```
var template = "<span>{fullname} ({name})</span>";
var html = template({ fullname: data.fullname, name: data.name });
```

To name a few:

- http://handlebarsjs.com/
- http://mustache.github.io/
- http://underscorejs.org/

Underscore is more a library tool belt, but it provides a simple templating engine that works well for common use.

Comment: Too much for my requirements, but worth looking into! Thanks!

Comment: Please stick to the tags, as the javascript tag wiki states: ***Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.***

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the transformation you are trying to achieve is, but I can tell you that you should not be using regex to achieve it! Transform your JSON into JavaScript objects using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), transform the objects directly, then convert back to JSON via [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Actually, I have to allow external configuration by 3rd persons. I have to look for instances of "data.<value>", where value could be whatever, within the template string, and replace it with a value taken from my source. I don't have to manipulate the JSON file, as I've loaded it before. I only have to manipulate the templateString